# Cisco QSFP loopback device recognized but 'not connected' with status light off

Tags: cisco, switch

I have tried plugging a QSFP28 loopback device into port on a cisco switch. I can see that the chip is recognized when I do 'show interface status' as I can see the model listed but it is 'not connected'. Status light is going from orange when unplugged to off with no light when plugged in.

Interface is apparently not shutdown and should be active. I entered 'no shutdown' and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

These ports need a couple of commands to work

```
switch(config-if)# speed 100000
switch(config-if)# no negotiate auto
switch(config-if)# negotiate auto
```

Then run shutdown followed by no shutdown on the port

This is what I did and the port came online